# Как включить базу данных в проект C#

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, сервер

Есть база данных на локальном сервере SQL Server 2014 с четырьмя таблицами объемом 1.5 GB. Суть программы искать в базе данных записи с критериями который задает пользователь. Программа написана и вполне нормально работает. Надо сделать так, чтобы программа работала и у других пользователей, у которых не установлен сервер. Как это реализовать? 
Была идея сериализовать данные, но так , как я понимаю, придется десериализовать все данные и только потом искать нужные записи.

Comment: Например, вы можете превратить программу в WCF-сервер, клиентские программы пусть коннектятся на сервер и получают результаты.

Comment: А что мешает программе коннектиться к серверу с других машин? Намекаю на архитектуру "клиент-сервер". Ну и вообще-то про архитектуру решения думают ДО того как его реализовывать, иначе переделывать почти всё.

Comment: Программу написал для учебных целей, и она мне вполне удовлетворяет, вопрос касается реализации БЕЗ сервера

Comment: Приведите типичный запрос. Вполне возможно, что SQL можно заменить поиском по индексу в специализированном формате.

Comment: Еще, желательно, приведите схему данных.

Comment: Схема - телефонный справочник Есть 4 таблицы (4 Операторы) с столбцами ID Owner Number Address
Пользователь вводит данные программа ищет совпадения в указанных столбцах

Answer (score 1):

Используйте встраиваемую СУБД. К примеру, [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)

Можно использовать вот этот пакет: [`System.Data.SQLite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite)

Comment: Не найдется ли времени у вас показать / объяснить как  сделать это? skype xoro-masiv

Comment: А что объяснять-то? Подключаете пакет через nuget и используете. СУБД как СУБД. хранимок нет, но и так неплохо получается.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую. Отпишусь, Спасибо

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Все получается, но теперь проблема с юникодом... Известная проблема в SQLite

Comment: @KhorenMansuryan э... какая такая проблема с юникодом? Если что-то не так - задайте лучше отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Проблема в том что по умолчанию в SQLite для оператора Like поддерживается Case_Insesitive_Collation только для английских букв, Впрочем это отдельная тема

Answer (score -1):

Варианты решения задачи:

1. использовать к примеру SQL Server CE и устанавливать каждому пользователю файл базы данных *.sdf. Разумеется придётся также поменять sql-коннектор.
2. сериализовать данные (например в формате xml) и осуществлять поиск напрямую в файлах без использования СУБД. В этом случае искать данные можно и без десериализации, просто построчно считывая и разбирая данные из файлов, в том числе и заархивированных.